# C - Protect Persistent Settings

Tags: c, constants

I have a C program which has always used hard coded define statements for a few settings. Example...

```
#define TRIGGER_TIMEOUT 50000
```

This has worked just fine. Now, this setting is to become adjustable. Example...

```
g_ulTriggerTimeout = ReadEEPROM(TRIGGER_TIMEOUT_OFFSET);
```

If persistent storage is detected (EEPROM) then the value will be read in and used. So, my safe literal value is now at risk of being corrupted (inadvertently written changed). I need to make this variable a constant, however I also need to read in the initial values from EEPROM. How is this scenario typically solved?

Comment: Can't you set your linker script to put this var at the EEPROM adress?

Comment: Unfortunately the EEPROM is external.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is IMHO one of those cases where bending the rules is ok.

```
const int g_ulTriggerTimeout; //declare somewhere making sure it is in a writable section (see comment below from undur)

/* later */

//just for this assignment make it modifiable
*((int*) &g_ulTriggerTimeout) = ReadEEPROM(TRIGGER_TIMEOUT_OFFSET);
```

Comment: This is not portable. I'd even guess this will not work on most platforms.

Comment: @undur_gongor Why is this not portable? Note i just fixed it to take the adress of `g_ul...`

Comment: I too would like to know why this is not portable? I prefer this solution because (right or wrong) I typically place my globals at the top of the .c file and all of my persistent settings are loaded in one function call (GetSettings()).

Comment: "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined." (ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 6.7.3, §5). E.g. the variable could be put into a ROM area.

Comment: @undur_gongor That is correct. But probably (since he must be modifying it in a function, this is c) it is not in any read-only area as ATM it is not `const` qualified. But i will take your note to consideration and update my answer.

Comment: Then it is still UB (although it will most probably work). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051969/c-accessing-a-non-const-through-const-declaration for details.

Answer (score 1):

I do not like bending the rules (invoking undefinded behaviour) like [RedX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9994355/280314) does. Therefore, I now give a C standard-compliant solution. The price is having a constant function instead of a constant variable.

```
int g_ulTriggerTimeout()
{
    static int done; // statically initialized to zero
    static int value;
    if( !done )
    {
        value = haveEEPROM ? ReadEEPROM(TRIGGER_TIMEOUT_OFFSET)
                                      : TRIGGER_TIMEOUT;
        done = 1;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Following is my first answer, it is however only valid in C++:

```
const int g_ulTriggerTimeout = haveEEPROM ? ReadEEPROM(TRIGGER_TIMEOUT_OFFSET)
                                          : TRIGGER_TIMEOUT;
```

Comment: This does not help against accidental modification of `g_ulTriggerTimeout` later in the program.

Comment: @undur_gongor, ok, let me add a `const`

Comment: It is probably embedded development and dev there seem to like spaghetti code + declaring far away from first assignment (i'm an embedded dev). So it is likely the assignment and declaration are not in the same line. Plus the var is probably global.

Comment: @RedX My example is out of context but if it appeared at global scope it would define a global constant. Also, if the OP wants a solution, he can forgo spaghettis and just use this simple constant definition.

Comment: The initialization of a "global" variable has to be a constant value. You cannot call functions then.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (portably/with C).

If you have to modify the variable in your program (by reading it from EEPROM), you cannot lock it against modification by your program.

There might be platform specific means to achieve that though.