# Is it valid to treat an extern global as const when the definition is not const?

Tags: c, standards, standards-compliance, c89

Say I have a compilation unit **file1.c**, which declares a file-scope variable like so:

```c
int my_variable = 12;
```

Then, in another compilation unit **file2.c**, I create an extern declaration for that variable, but declare it as `const`:

```
extern const int my_variable;
```

This will compile and work fine with gcc , using `-Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic`. However, the C89 standard says *For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type*. Adding `const` to the declaration adds a restriction rather than avoiding one. Is this safe and valid C? What would be the best practice in setting this up with header files?

Comment: May be the compiler would complain if it was the other way, if you discard the `const` quialifier. But I'm not really sure.

Comment: I am pretty sure [C — Accessing a non-const through const declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8051969/1708801) covers this case.

Comment: Probably worth specifying the exact C standard version you are referring to.

Comment: @Clifford: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.3 in *semantics*.

Comment: You should generally "improve" the question rather than answer by comment - done.  It was worthwhile because the question @ShafikYaghmour linked to relates to C99 rather than C89; the `-ansi` option is equivalent to `-std=c90` and ISO C90 and ANSI C89 are identical.  However it is perhaps too late because it has now been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour : No I was just pointing out that the two questions specified different language standards, and may differ in this respect.  I referenced you simply because you made the suggestion (entirely appropriately).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's clearly undefined as the declarations don't match. As you noted, `const int` and `int` aren't compatible types. A diagnostic is required only if they appear in the same scope.

It isn't safe in practice either, consider

```
$ cat test1.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern const int n;
void foo(void);

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", n);
    foo();
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
$ cat test2.c
int n;
void foo(void) { ++n; }
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic test1.c test2.c && ./a.out
0
1
$ gcc -O1 -std=c99 -pedantic test1.c test2.c && ./a.out
0
0
```

Gcc assumes that `n` isn't changed by `foo()` when optimizing, because it may assume the definition of `n` is of a compatible type, thus `const`.

Chances are that you get the expected behaviour with also `volatile`-qualifying `n` in `test1.c`, but as far as the C standard is concerned, this is still undefined.

The best way I can think of to prevent the user from accidentally modifying `n` is to declare a pointer to `const`, something along

```
int my_real_variable;
const int *const my_variable = &my_real_variable;
```

or perhaps some macro

```
#define my_variable (*(const int *)&my_variable)
```

With C99, `my_real_variable` can be avoided via a compound literal:

```
const int *const my_variable_ptr = &(int){ 12 };
```

It would be legal to cast away `const` here (as the `int` object itself isn't `const`), but the cast would be required, preventing accidental modification.

Comment: This answers the question well; that example is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In this case the definition and declaration appear in separate translation units, so the *compiler* cannot perform any type or qualifier checks.  The symbols are resolved by the *linker* and in this case it seems that the linker is not enforcing this qualifier matching.

If the definition and the declaration appeared in the same translation unit; for example if you placed the `extern` declaration in a header file and *included* it in *file1.c*, then I would imagine that the compiler *would* complain.  By placing them in separate translation units, the compiler never sees both so cannot perform the check.

Comment: I assume from this that the behaviour of the linker in this situation is implementation-specific? In this situation, all I know is that C name decoration pays no attention to `const` (whereas C++ does, for example.)